# Tables spanning multiple pages in azure form recognizer? (v 3.0)

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to extract data from invoices that have one table that can span multiple pages (see image for example)[image: Sample document with table spanning in two pages]

For this task I am using Microsoft's Form Recognizer Studio (Custom Model) version 3.0

My problem comes with the table. Once I train the model it only identifies the line items from page 1, it does not consider any line item from other pages but the first.

Is there any way to work around? Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Recognizer custom does not yet support tables that span multiple pages. This feature is coming soon stay tuned. Until then did you try out the Form Recognizer invoice service ? It should extract the line items from both pages. Another option is to split the document to its pages and then send it to the custom model and see if it extracts the table from both pages.

Comment: Thanks for corfirming that the form recognizer custom models do not support multiple page spanned tables. However, I am interested in custom built models, as the invoices I am dealing with have some complex fields that the invoice model is not able to identify correctly

Comment: Is this feature available??

Comment: Please note Form Recognizer now supports table spanning multiple pages. Custom form models now support tabular fields across pages. See What's New here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/whats-new?tabs=csharp#form-recognizer-v30-preview-release

Invoice pre-built model supports line items spanning multiple pages also.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to use Chrome Dev Tools to capture the data of the request for each auto-label on each page. That way you can get the system to do all the hard work of labelling the table data for you.

E.g.

1. [Page 1](https://pastebin.com/raw/wV6KH21K)
2. [Page 2](https://pastebin.com/raw/r2yJ05k1)
3. etc

Then i just modified the JSON to update the line number to be in sequential order

Then joined the Line item arrays together and manually `PUT` a request using the original headers/auth etc.